# Special Characters in FPDF with PHP

Tags: php, character, fpdf

I have a web form that users can fill out and that content fills up a PDF with FPDF and PHP. When a user enters a word with an apostrophe, a slash appears before it on the PDF.

Similarly, special characters like trademark symbols are encoded wrong.

The FPDF FAQs say to use:

```
$str = utf8_decode($str);
```

But I'm just not sure how to apply that to the whole PDF. I'm trying to think about it as if it was an HTML page but that isn't helping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Figured this out by doing the following (pagesubtitle is the name of the text field in the form):

```
$reportSubtitle = stripslashes($_POST['pagesubtitle']);
$reportSubtitle = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $reportSubtitle);
```

Then print it out:

```
$pdf->Write (6, $reportSubtitle);
```

This will remove any unwanted slashes following apostrophes, as well as use the 'iconv' function to print special characters such as ™

Answer (score 25):

All of the above did not work for me, but I did get it to work.

I managed to do it "the barbarian way" by just translating every weird character to its url value. Then simply decode the url and voila!

```
function em($word) {

    $word = str_replace("@","%40",$word);
    $word = str_replace("`","%60",$word);
    $word = str_replace("¢","%A2",$word);
    $word = str_replace("£","%A3",$word);
    $word = str_replace("¥","%A5",$word);
    $word = str_replace("|","%A6",$word);
    $word = str_replace("«","%AB",$word);
    $word = str_replace("¬","%AC",$word);
    $word = str_replace("¯","%AD",$word);
    $word = str_replace("º","%B0",$word);
    $word = str_replace("±","%B1",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ª","%B2",$word);
    $word = str_replace("µ","%B5",$word);
    $word = str_replace("»","%BB",$word);
    $word = str_replace("¼","%BC",$word);
    $word = str_replace("½","%BD",$word);
    $word = str_replace("¿","%BF",$word);
    $word = str_replace("À","%C0",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Á","%C1",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Â","%C2",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ã","%C3",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ä","%C4",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Å","%C5",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Æ","%C6",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ç","%C7",$word);
    $word = str_replace("È","%C8",$word);
    $word = str_replace("É","%C9",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ê","%CA",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ë","%CB",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ì","%CC",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Í","%CD",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Î","%CE",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ï","%CF",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ð","%D0",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ñ","%D1",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ò","%D2",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ó","%D3",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ô","%D4",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Õ","%D5",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ö","%D6",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ø","%D8",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ù","%D9",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ú","%DA",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Û","%DB",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ü","%DC",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Ý","%DD",$word);
    $word = str_replace("Þ","%DE",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ß","%DF",$word);
    $word = str_replace("à","%E0",$word);
    $word = str_replace("á","%E1",$word);
    $word = str_replace("â","%E2",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ã","%E3",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ä","%E4",$word);
    $word = str_replace("å","%E5",$word);
    $word = str_replace("æ","%E6",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ç","%E7",$word);
    $word = str_replace("è","%E8",$word);
    $word = str_replace("é","%E9",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ê","%EA",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ë","%EB",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ì","%EC",$word);
    $word = str_replace("í","%ED",$word);
    $word = str_replace("î","%EE",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ï","%EF",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ð","%F0",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ñ","%F1",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ò","%F2",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ó","%F3",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ô","%F4",$word);
    $word = str_replace("õ","%F5",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ö","%F6",$word);
    $word = str_replace("÷","%F7",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ø","%F8",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ù","%F9",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ú","%FA",$word);
    $word = str_replace("û","%FB",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ü","%FC",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ý","%FD",$word);
    $word = str_replace("þ","%FE",$word);
    $word = str_replace("ÿ","%FF",$word);
    return $word;
}
```

And of course me calling the function

```
$weirdword = "Días, Miércoles, Sábado,miércoles"; //Some spanish days
$weirdword = em($weirdword);
$weirdword = urldecode($weirdword);
echo $weirdword;
```

Giving output:

*Días, Miércoles, Sábado,miércoles*

Comment: You can give str_replace arrays as parameters.

Comment: I realise this is a massive hack anyway, but might be cleaner to at least `return urldecode($word);` at the end of your `em` function. Anyway, this worked when nothing else would, so a million thanks! :)

Comment: cool, it works :).. Also return urldecode($word) in em function could be worth :).. Many thanks !

Comment: The best solution this problem can have!

Answer (score 10):

none of above solutions worked for me, so I solved the problem like this:

```
$this->AddFont('Arial','','arial.php');
$this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$this->Cell(0,5,iconv("UTF-8", "CP1250//TRANSLIT", $string),0,1,'L');
```

Before trying the above lines, do the following:

Copy from c:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf to the /tutorial folder of FPDF.

Edit the content of makefont.php

```
require('../makefont/makefont.php');
MakeFont('arial.ttf','cp1250');
```

Execute makefont.php

Copy the following files to the /font folder of FPDF:
    arial.php
    arial.ttf
    arial.z

Finally, define the "font folder". Open fpdf.php (main library file) and add:

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font');
```

The PDF works for me with all special characters, I believe it was the problem in the Arial font itself, which FPDF originally uses. It should work with other fonts aswell, if they support your characters. Good luck!

Comment: I know this is very old, but still - thank you very much! This seems to be the correct solution to this problem. I am also creating (or converting) a `ttf` font for FPDF with `cp1250` and now every character is displayed correctly. Nice!

Answer (score 7):

None of above had solved my problem. I had solved it by the following way:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US');

$value = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $value);
$fpdf->Cell(140, 6, $value, 1);
```

Hope you will be helpful.

**Reference:** [***Link***](https://isabelcastillo.com/international-characters-encoding-fpdf)

Comment: Really, great. That is what I was searching for 3 hours.

Answer (score 3):

This did it for me:
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", *your-text-var-here*)

Answer (score 2):

Below works for me (Using FPDF):

---

```
function em_jaz($word) {
$word = str_replace('+', ' ', $word);
$word = str_replace("%C3%A9","%E9",$word);          /* é */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A8","%E8",$word);          /* è */
$word = str_replace("%C3%AE","%EE",$word);          /* î */
$word = str_replace("%26rsquo%3B","%27",$word);     /* ' */
$word = str_replace("%C3%89","%C9",$word);          /* É */
$word = str_replace("%C3%8A","%CA",$word);          /* Ê */ 
$word = str_replace("%C3%8B","%CB",$word);          /* Ë */
$word = str_replace("%C3%8C","%CC",$word);          /* Ì */
$word = str_replace("%C3%8D","%CD",$word);          /* Í */
$word = str_replace("%C3%8E","%CE",$word);          /* Î */
$word = str_replace("%C3%8F","%CF",$word);          /* Ï */
$word = str_replace("%C3%90","%D0",$word);          /* Ð */
$word = str_replace("%C3%91","%D1",$word);          /* Ñ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%92","%D2",$word);          /* Ò */
$word = str_replace("%C3%93","%D3",$word);          /* Ó */
$word = str_replace("%C3%94","%D4",$word);          /* Ô */
$word = str_replace("%C3%95","%D5",$word);          /* Õ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%96","%D6",$word);          /* Ö */
$word = str_replace("%C3%98","%D8",$word);          /* Ø */                 
$word = str_replace("%C3%99","%D9",$word);          /* Ù */
$word = str_replace("%C3%9A","%DA",$word);          /* Ú */
$word = str_replace("%C3%9B","%DB",$word);          /* Û */
$word = str_replace("%C3%9C","%DC",$word);          /* Ü */
$word = str_replace("%C3%9D","%DD",$word);          /* Ý */
$word = str_replace("%C3%9E","%DE",$word);          /* Þ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%9F","%DF",$word);          /* ß */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A0","%E0",$word);          /* à */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A1","%E1",$word);          /* á */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A2","%E2",$word);          /* â */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A3","%E3",$word);          /* ã */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A4","%E4",$word);          /* ä */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A5","%E5",$word);          /* å */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A6","%E6",$word);          /* æ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%A7","%E7",$word);          /* ç */
$word = str_replace("%C3%AA","%EA",$word);          /* ê */
$word = str_replace("%C3%AB","%EB",$word);          /* ë */
$word = str_replace("%C3%AC","%EC",$word);          /* ì */
$word = str_replace("%C3%AD","%ED",$word);          /* í */
$word = str_replace("%C3%AF","%EF",$word);          /* ï */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B0","%F0",$word);          /* ð */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B1","%F1",$word);          /* ñ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B2","%F2",$word);          /* ò */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B3","%F3",$word);          /* ó */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B4","%F4",$word);          /* ô */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B5","%F5",$word);          /* õ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B6","%F6",$word);          /* ö */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B7","%F7",$word);          /* ÷ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B8","%F8",$word);          /* ø */
$word = str_replace("%C3%B9","%F9",$word);          /* ù */
$word = str_replace("%C3%BA","%FA",$word);          /* ú */
$word = str_replace("%C3%BB","%FB",$word);          /* û */
$word = str_replace("%C3%BC","%FC",$word);          /* ü */
$word = str_replace("%C3%BD","%FD",$word);          /* ý */
$word = str_replace("%C3%BE","%FE",$word);          /* þ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%BF","%FF",$word);          /* ÿ */ 
$word = str_replace("%40","%40",$word);             /* @ */
$word = str_replace("%60","%60",$word);             /* ` */
$word = str_replace("%C2%A2","%A2",$word);          /* ¢ */
$word = str_replace("%C2%A3","%A3",$word);          /* £ */
$word = str_replace("%C2%A5","%A5",$word);          /* ¥ */
$word = str_replace("%7C","%A6",$word);             /* | */
$word = str_replace("%C2%AB","%AB",$word);          /* « */
$word = str_replace("%C2%AC","%AC",$word);          /* ¬ */
$word = str_replace("%C2%AF","%AD",$word);          /* ¯ */
$word = str_replace("%C2%BA","%B0",$word);          /* º */
$word = str_replace("%C2%B1","%B1",$word);          /* ± */
$word = str_replace("%C2%AA","%B2",$word);          /* ª */
$word = str_replace("%C2%B5","%B5",$word);          /* µ */
$word = str_replace("%C2%BB","%BB",$word);          /* » */
$word = str_replace("%C2%BC","%BC",$word);          /* ¼ */
$word = str_replace("%C2%BD","%BD",$word);          /* ½ */
$word = str_replace("%C2%BF","%BF",$word);          /* ¿ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%80","%C0",$word);          /* À */
$word = str_replace("%C3%81","%C1",$word);          /* Á */
$word = str_replace("%C3%82","%C2",$word);          /* Â */
$word = str_replace("%C3%83","%C3",$word);          /* Ã */
$word = str_replace("%C3%84","%C4",$word);          /* Ä */
$word = str_replace("%C3%85","%C5",$word);          /* Å */
$word = str_replace("%C3%86","%C6",$word);          /* Æ */
$word = str_replace("%C3%87","%C7",$word);          /* Ç */
$word = str_replace("%C3%88","%C8",$word);          `/`* È */
return $word;
}
```

$content = urlencode($content);

$content = urldecode($pdf->em_jaz($content));

Comment: Welcome to SO! When providing code asan answer, it is helpful to explain how your code resolves the OP's problem :)

Answer (score 1):

> This class is a modified version of FPDF that adds UTF-8 support.
>   Moreover, it embeds only the necessary parts of the fonts that are
>   used in the document, making the file size much smaller than if the
>   whole fonts were embedded. These features were originally developed
>   for the mPDF project.

http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Answer (score 1):

I have used this as `$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/','', $str);` for me has been enough, I eliminate the not alphanumerical characters

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the function PDF recommends?

```
$text = utf8_decode($text);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode it this way assuming your special character is "°C"

```
> $pdf->Cell(X(int),Y(int),iconv("UTF-8", "CP1250//TRANSLIT", '°C'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution using the following approach:

```
$title = "Your text with some special characters";
$title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$title = iconv('UTF-8', "CP1250//TRANSLIT", $title);
```

OR

```
$title = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode($title));
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this simple function: `utf8_encode($txt)`. It works for me.