# FPDF encoding in footer

Tags: php, encoding, fpdf

I have a problem using FPDF while using special character like é, è or à.

I used `$é = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', 'é');` and then I use it like this `$pdf->Cell(0,0,'Donn'.$é.'es',0,1);`. I know this is not the best way to work with but that's not a big deal...

The real problem is that we can not use variable in header or footer. Or I have to write a sentence in the footer with special character. How can I proceed to this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special Characters in FPDF with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514076/special-characters-in-fpdf-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a global variable.

In the main code

```
global $à ;
$à = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', 'à');
```

In the header/footer

```
$à  = $GLOBALS['à'];
```