# Special Character like (≥, ≤) shown as "?" in TCPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, special-characters, tcpdf

I generate the PDF using TCPDF in Codeigniter, PDF is generated dynamically and providing selection of fonts to user from Courier, Helvetica and Times New Roman. But when user add special Character like **(≥, ≤)** it shown in PDF as question mark **(?)**.

I know the solution that if I set font to either **"dejavusans"** or **"freeserif"** it will fix the issue but it is changing font of PDF. So problem is if I set font fix to either of them will loose the functionality of font selection to user.

Can anyone help me to get out from this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `utf8_decode()` to decode your string before generate PDF file..

Comment: I tried utf8_decode() but its not working:(

Comment: This answer should be able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514076/special-characters-in-fpdf-with-php

Comment: I can try the answer of **Oscar Bout** but is it good to put static like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special Characters in FPDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514076/special-characters-in-fpdf-with-php)

Comment: No issue i did str replace with this <= both means same