# Special Characters in FPDF

Tags: php, special-characters, fpdf

I am generating a PDF report with using FPDF and there is some characters like delta and alpha `(δ , Δ , α)` etc... But FPDF doesn't appear to work with such characters.

I tried the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514076/special-characters-in-fpdf-with-php) solution but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

here is a sample :

```
$pdf->Multicell(10 , 20 , 'δz (mm)' , 1  ,'C');
```

Comment: please share *your* code

Comment: i am just printing some special characters in pdf but i ve edited my post have a look :p

Answer (score 1):

To print the delta (and other special characters) you need to use the included Symbol font.

[image: a]

You can view a font dump of all the included fonts at this link.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/fontdump.pdf

On page 2 of the PDF the Symbol font delta character is listed as code 68.

[image: dir]

Set the font:

`$pdf->SetFont('symbol');`

To print the delta character you would use chr(68) for the string argument.

`$pdf->Multicell(10 , 20 , chr(68) , 1  ,'C');`