# FPDF - Some special characters not working

Tags: php, fpdf

I was able to print special character like ™

But when I have to print Φ, I got error "iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string"

Here's what I've tried so far:

$line = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1250//TRANSLIT', $line);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special Characters in FPDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514076/special-characters-in-fpdf-with-php)

Comment: @KenLee I've tried all of those but it does not work with some special character like Φ

Comment: Greek letters are available in the Symbol font, as can be seen [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/fontdump.pdf). Uppercase phi is `chr(70)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine. It's a **notice**, not an error. Here's the Euro example from [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

```
<?php
    $text = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";

    echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
    echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
    echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;
?>
```

which is going to output:

```
Original : This is the Euro symbol '€'.
TRANSLIT : This is the Euro symbol 'EUR'.
IGNORE   : This is the Euro symbol ''.
Plain    :

Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string on line 7
```

There are more hints on how to handle different scenarios in the comment section of the [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).